# Change selected text via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
/*
keyCode: 8
keyIdentifier: "U+0008"
*/
if(e.keyCode === 16 && getSelectionText() != "") {
    e.preventDefault();
      replaceSelectedText(strcon(getSelectionText()));
    }
});

function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}

function strcon(givenString) {
    var b = '';
    var a = givenString;
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a.charCodeAt(i) >= 65 && a.charCodeAt(i) <= 90) {
            b = b + a.charAt(i).toLowerCase();
        }
        else
            b = b + a.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
    }
    return b;
}

function replaceSelectedText(replacementText) {
    var sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(replacementText));
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.text = replacementText;
    }
}
```

The code I have right now seems to change the appearance of the actual text instead of actually changing it. For example, when I'm on Facebook and I press the certain key, the text seems to have changed but then when I press enter, the text goes back to what it was before.

I believe the issue is with the function `replaceSelectedText` but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Any ideas?

No JQuery please.

https://jsfiddle.net/1rvz3696/

Comment: can you please create jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: @user2181397 Done and done

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  I tried your jsfiddle:  I entered "hello foobar".  I select a word and press shift key.  Then the word appears before the input box as capital letters.  What of this is undesired behavior?

Comment: @ILovephp123 I still don't get it.. Your fiddle works fine to me or I really still dont get it

Comment: @owler, the goal is to replace the selected text, not add it somewhere else

Comment: @choz the goal is to replace the selected text, not add it somewhere else

Comment: @ILovephp123 So, if I input `'abc'` and `select` it then press `shift`, I should change `abc` to another word? or..

Comment: @choz, Correct, it should change it to `ABC`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to get your `textarea` element to replace the value in it. This is how your `replaceSelectedText` function should look like,

```
function replaceSelectedText(text) {
  var txtArea = document.getElementById('myTextArea');
  if (txtArea.selectionStart != undefined) {
    var startPos = txtArea.selectionStart;
    var endPos = txtArea.selectionEnd;
    selectedText = txtArea.value.substring(startPos, endPos);
    txtArea.value = txtArea.value.slice(0, startPos) + text + txtArea.value.slice(endPos);
  }
}
```

And here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1rvz3696/1/).

Without specific `id`, you can replace `txtArea` to this.

```
var txtArea = document.activeElement;
```

And another [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1rvz3696/2/)

Comment: But what if there's no specific ID, I want it to be used in any place where a person can put text